Two-yearly time series ticks in Dygraphs
By default, Dygraphs uses an internal algorithm to determine the best labelling for the x (time series) axis. However, it offers a number of overrides which can be used to force a particular labelling. These include ANNUAL for yearly ticks, HOURLY for hourly ticks, etc.
I have a dataset of annual data which, on a standard sized PC screen, falls annoyingly between two stools. The Dygraphs default only labels every ten years, which is too widely spaced for data covering a 23 year span (the data runs from 2000 to 2023). However, if I force it to use annual spacing, the tick labels are too close together and overlap.
What I would like, therefore, is to label every other year (essentially, every even year, so the labels will be on 2000, 2002, 2004, etc up to 2022).
However, there is no built-in override to force two-yearly (bi-annual) spacing. So I'm going to need to roll my own function for this.
This is what I'm currently using in the x axis options:
ticker: function(min, max, pixels, opts, dygraph, vals) {
        return Dygraph.getDateAxis(min, max, Dygraph.ANNUAL, opts, dygraph);
}

Can anyone give me some clues as to what I need in there to get a two-yearly tick label?

This looks like it will be tricky to achieve.
Looking at the code (dygraph-tickers.js) Dygraphs.ANNUAL is simply an index into an enumeration which defines all the supported ticker placements.
The enumeration for ANNUAL is:
TICK_PLACEMENT[Granularity.ANNUAL] = {datefield: DateField.DATEFIELD_Y, step: 1, spacing: 1000 * 86400 * 365.2524};

You could make your own version of this entry with:
{datefield: DateField.DATEFIELD_Y, step: 2, spacing: 1000 * 86400 * 2 * 365.2524}

Presumably Dygraph.getDateAxis looks up this enum internally, so I don't know how you would be able to inject your customised version into it.
Sorry it's not a full answer, but that's as close as I can get.
